# How to subset data.table using keys

Tags: r, data.table, key, subset

I have a data.table and I'm trying to subset it so I get the lowest TEST_RESULT by ID and LAB_DT:

```r
DT <- data.table::data.table(ID=c("1","1","1","2","2","3","3","3"),
                             LAB_DT=lubridate::as_date(c("1992-11-01",
                                                         "1992-11-01",
                                                         "1992-11-02",
                                                         "1992-11-04",
                                                         "1992-11-04",
                                                         "1992-11-06",
                                                         "1992-11-06",
                                                         "1992-11-08")),
                             TEST_RESULT=c(5.4,5.8,5.2,5.6,6,6,7,8))
setkeyv(DT,c("ID","LAB_DT","TEST_RESULT"))

   ID     LAB_DT TEST_RESULT
1:  1 1992-11-01         5.4
2:  1 1992-11-01         5.8
3:  1 1992-11-02         5.2
4:  2 1992-11-04         5.6
5:  2 1992-11-04         6.0
6:  3 1992-11-06         6.0
7:  3 1992-11-06         7.0
8:  3 1992-11-08         8.0
```

I have already successfully done this via my own method:

```r
DT[,FIRST.LAB_DT:=0]
DT[, FIRST.LAB_DT := c(1L, FIRST.LAB_DT[-1]), by = .(ID,LAB_DT)]

   ID     LAB_DT TEST_RESULT FIRST.LAB_DT
1:  1 1992-11-01         5.4            1
2:  1 1992-11-01         5.8            0
3:  1 1992-11-02         5.2            1
4:  2 1992-11-04         5.6            1
5:  2 1992-11-04         6.0            0
6:  3 1992-11-06         6.0            1
7:  3 1992-11-06         7.0            0
8:  3 1992-11-08         8.0            1

DT[FIRST.LAB_DT==1,]

   ID     LAB_DT TEST_RESULT FIRST.LAB_DT
1:  1 1992-11-01         5.4            1
2:  1 1992-11-02         5.2            1
3:  2 1992-11-04         5.6            1
4:  3 1992-11-06         6.0            1
5:  3 1992-11-08         8.0            1
```

However, the actual data.table I'm working with has ~8e6 rows and [I recently found](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) that you can subset data.table using the keys in a much faster manner.

Would anyone know how to produce the same final output using keys?

Comment: Nothing to do with keys, but I think it will be the fastest way to get the result: `DT[DT[, .I[which.min(TEST_RESULT)], .(ID, LAB_DT)]$V1]`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I second on this to be the the fastest. I think there was this question from *hadley* that asked about performance of subsetting in `data.table` and there were good discussions/answer on that thread. I'll see if I can find it. p.s. found it already.

Answer (score 1):

Since you report that your current approach works, your data is apparently sorted by increasing TEST_RESULT already. In this case, you can just drop duplicates to keep the first row per group:

```
unique(DT, by=c("ID", "LAB_DT"))
```

In general, if it is not sorted, you could roll from `-Inf`. Like your code, this selects only one row even if there are ties for the min value:

```
mDT = unique(DT[, .(ID, LAB_DT)])[, TEST_RESULT := -Inf]
DT[DT[mDT, on=names(mDT), roll=-Inf, which=TRUE]]
```

Finally, if you only have these three columns, you can just use the `min` function which is optimized for speed here (see `?GForce`):

```
DT[, .(TEST_RESULT = min(TEST_RESULT)), by=.(ID, LAB_DT)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
group_by(ID,LAB_DT) %>% 
slice(which.min(TEST_RESULT))
```

Comment: OP explicitly asked for a `data.table` solution; not sure how a `dplyr`-based solution helps here.